# Unwanted bounce on edge

Tags: unity-game-engine

There are two planes next to each other. Each plane has a mesh collider. Randomly, when the capsule (with a rigidbody and a capsule collider) crosses the edges it bounces.

Do you know why ?

[image]

Comment: What works for me is to set the value of "Default Contact Offset" to 0.001. 
This field replace the older "Min Penetration For Penalty"

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens if the planes don't align. Make sure there is no gap between the planes and that they are on the same y position.
If this won't fix you problem, you might want to consider using Unity's CharacterController and adjusting the step size which will, rather than bounce, slide/snap the player to position.